# Trying to prove $\bigcup_{A \in\mathfrak{P}(X)}A=X \, \text{ and }\,\bigcap_{A \in\mathfrak{P}(X)}A= \emptyset $

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am trying to prove that
$$
  \bigcup_{A  \in\mathfrak{P}(X)}A=X \qquad \text{ and }\qquad \bigcap_{A  \in\mathfrak{P}(X)}A= \emptyset 
$$
with $\mathfrak{P}(X) $ being the powerset of a set $ X $.

"$\subset $":  We know that $ A  \in\mathfrak{P}(X)   \Leftrightarrow   A \subset X $ therefore $ x  \in A  \Rightarrow x \in X $ so $ \bigcup_{A  \in\mathfrak{P}(X)}A\subset X $.

"$ \supset $": We know that per definition $ x  \in X  \Leftrightarrow\left\{ x \right\}  \in\mathfrak{P}(X)  $ therefore for every $ x \in X $ exists a subset $ A \subset X$ with $ x \in A $ so we have $ \bigcup_{A  \in\mathfrak{P}(X)}A\supset X $.

"$ \subset $": Because the definition of $ \bigcap_{A \in\mathfrak{P}(X)}A  $ is $ \left\{ x  \in X \colon  \forall A  \in\mathfrak{P}(X) \text{ such that }x \in A \right\}  $ and $ \emptyset  \in\mathfrak{P}(X) $ (per definition) and $ x  \notin \emptyset   $ therefore $ \bigcap_{A  \in\mathfrak{P}(X)}A \subset \emptyset $.

"$ \supset $": Obiously we know $ \bigcap_{A  \in\mathfrak{P}(X)}A \supset \emptyset $, because there exists a set $ A \in\mathfrak{P}(X) $ that is the empty set.

Can someone verify this and tell me if this is complete?

Comment: $x\in X \iff \{x\} \in \mathfrak{P}(X)$ is not true when the set has mroe than 2 elements, because $\{x_1,x_2\}\in\mathfrak{P}(X)$ however $(x_1,x_2)\in X \times X$. On the other hand, note that it is always the case that $X\in\mathfrak{P}(X)$ since $X\subset X$. Therefore $X\subset \cup_{A}A$

Comment: Your reasoning about the intersection is unclear and seems wrong. Remember that $A\cap B=\{x\mid x\in A \text{ AND } x\in B\}$
For the second case, you could also use De Morgan's law together with the fact that $A\in \mathfrak{P}(X)\iff X\setminus A\in \mathfrak{P}(X)$.

Comment: @Surb That's the definition from the book. Maybe because $\{x\}$ it means all subsets of $\mathfrak{P}(X)$ with only one element and you used two for $\{x_1,x_2\}$.

Comment: Mhmm, you may then want to recall the definition of your book as it seems to be different from the classical definition of power set... What I know is $\mathfrak{P}(X)=\{A\colon A \subset X\}$.

Comment: @Surb I mean I have it open, it's:
$\emptyset\in \mathfrak{P}(X) , X\in \mathfrak{P}(X) $

$ x\in X \Leftrightarrow \{x\}\in \mathfrak{P}(X) $ 
and 

$Y\subset X \Leftrightarrow Y \in \mathfrak{P}(X) .$

Comment: I do not understand what the ordered pair $(x_{1}, x_{2}) \in X \times X$ has to do with the power set of $X$.

Comment: @Surb Which direction of the intersection seems wrong? The intersection of sets is a set that contains the empty set (if $X$ is empty than the intersection with itself is the empty again so also true). The other direction is true because we are looking for $x\in A$ for all $A$ and because there is a set $A$ that is the empty set and $x\notin \emptyset$ it is true, right?

Comment: @Surb $$x\in X\iff\{x\}\in\mathcal{P}(X)$$Is correct. As Jay says, why are you talking about $X\times X$?

Comment: The proof structure (showing four inclusions) is the right one. You can simplify your arguments by noting that $X \in \mathfrak{P}(X)$ and $\emptyset \in \mathfrak{P}(X)$.